# Buffers per frame

Tags: emacs, buffer, irc, gnus

Is it possible to have get subset of related buffers with each emacs frame
when switching and displaying buffers

I mean

- A frame that is dedicated for GNUS will show only gnus buffers
- A frame that is dedicated for ERC  will show only erc buffers
- A frame that is dedicated for Editing  will show only all other buffers

Comment: Any progress on this issue? I'm interested in exactly the same thing, this would make using emacs for sevaral things in parallel much more enjoyable

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I can find is ["Forcing Display in the Same Window"](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Force-Same-Window.html#Force-Same-Window).  But it is not exactly what you want.

I do not think there is any way to do what you want short of redefining all of the commands related to selecting buffers.  I would not mind being proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could get most of the way there using [Window Configurations](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Window-Configurations.html#Window-Configurations) and [Frame Configurations](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Frame-Configurations.html#Frame-Configurations), probably with some mode hooks. I've been meaning to really figure out a good way of doing this reliably, but haven't had time as of yet (which isn't really helpful I guess).

Anyhow, best of luck, maybe someone with more knowledge will have a better answer.